# Are there natural numbers that are not the descendant of 0?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, peano-axioms

Based on the Peano Axioms (wich are a way to correctly absolutely define the set of natural numbers - correct me if i'm wrong) it is possible to construct a set of symbols that doesn't quite look the way i imagine the natural numbers: [image: The successor-relation]

If there is a circle of other symbols next to the infinite row of known natural numbers, doesn't this also fit all the requirements?

So are there multiple unequal sets of natural numbers?

Comment: The axiom of induction fails for the structure above.

Comment: The peano axioms aren't so much definitions as... axioms. Definitions are new words for things that already exist. When working in the Peano axioms, one assumes there exists a structure satisfying those axioms... It's different. More like axioms for set theory or Euclidean geometry.

Answer (score 14):

The induction axiom ensures that $\Bbb N$ cannot contain a cycle like your $a,b,c$ cycle. It says that if

- $0\in A$, and
- for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $n\in A$ implies that $n+1\in A$,

then $A=\Bbb N$. Take $A$ to be everything in your diagram except $a,b$, and $c$; this $A$ satisfies both of these requirements, yet it’s not the whole set shown in your diagram. Thus, the set in your diagram doesn’t satisfy the Peano axioms, and indeed they characterize $\Bbb N$.

However, the induction axiom cannot be expressed in first-order logic, and there *are* structures other than $\Bbb N$ that satisfy the first-order counterpart of the Peano axioms, though they still don’t contain cycles. All of them are linearly ordered and consist of a copy of the standard $\Bbb N$ followed by copies of $\Bbb Z$ (so that everything except $0$ has a unique immediate predecessor). There are restrictions on how these copies of $\Bbb Z$ can be ordered relative to one another. For instance, the only possibility for a countable non-standard model looks like $\Bbb N$ followed by $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Z$ ordered lexicographically.

Comment: How does $\mathbb{N}$ followed by copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy the induction axiom? It seems I should be able to take $A$ to be the copy of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @arkeet: I need to revise that slightly. It doesn’t satisfy the second-order induction axiom that I stated; it *does* satisfy the first-order axiom schema that replaces the induction axiom if you try to give a corresponding first-order axiomatization.

Answer (score 0):

> If there is a circle of other symbols next to the infinite row of known natural numbers, doesn't this also fit all the requirements?

No. The structure indicated in your diagram violates the [axiom of induction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InductionAxiom.html):

$$\forall P\subset N:[0\in P \land \forall a\in P: S(a)\in P \implies P=N]$$

This axiom rules out the possibility of set $N$ being comprised of two or more disconnected parts, as in your diagram.

To prove this, we need only the following Peano Axioms:

$0\in N$

$S:N\to N$

Suppose we have $X$, as in your diagram, such that:

$X \subset N\space\space$  (in this case, we have $X=\{a, b,c \}$)

$X\ne \emptyset$

$0\notin X$

$\forall x\in X:\neg \exists y\in N:[y\notin X\land S(y)=x]$

Let $X'=N\setminus X$

It can then be shown that:

$$X'\subset N \land [0\in X' \land \forall x\in X': S(x)\in X'\land \exists x\in N: x\notin X']$$

Generalizing...

$$\exists P\subset N : [0\in P \land \forall x\in P: S(x)\in P\land \exists x\in N: x\notin P]]$$

Or equivalently, we have the negation of the induction principle:

$$\neg\forall P\subset N:[0\in P \land \forall a\in P: S(a)\in P \implies P=N]$$

> So are there multiple unequal sets of natural numbers?

If you have two structures $(N,S,0)$ and $(N',S',0')$ that satisfy the 5 Peano Axioms, they can be shown to be essentially identical ([order isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_isomorphism)). There would exist a bijection $f$ such that:

$f: N\to N'$

$f(0)=0'$

$\forall a \in N: f(S(a))=S'(f(a))$

**EDIT:**

See my [formal proof](http://dcproof.com/PurposeInductionAxiom.htm) in DC Proof format (149 lines). There I prove that no non-empty, proper subset $X$ of $N$, like your $\{a,b,c\}$, can be "disconnected" from $N\setminus X$ as you have indicated in your diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The induction axiom is:

If $P(0)$ holds, and if $P(n + 1)$ follows from $P(n)$, then $P$ is true of all values.

If you let $S = \{a, b, c\}$, and $P(n) = n \not \in S$, then the above axiom fails.

$P(0)$ is true, $P(n + 1)$ follows from $P(n)$ (it hold for $n \in S$ due to vacuous implication), but P doesn't hold for all numbers in your structure (it fails for $n \in S$).

So the induction axiom will fail for any structure with non-natural numbers, just let $S$ be the set of numbers not in the natural number chain.

Answer (score -1):

Going by wikipedia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms

The first 8 axioms (particularly 8): For every natural number n, S(n) = 0 is false. That is, there is no natural number whose successor is 0.) seem to assure that the is the "number line" 0->1->2->3.... and that it is infinite and not circular.  But they don't say any thing about there not being any a->b->c->d.... or oom<->pah. which are completely distinct and separate from this set of number lines.

They *do* state that they must be distinct though.  If S(S(S(....(a)))) = a then a $\ne $ S(S(.....(0))))).  Or if b $\not \in$ 0->1->2->3.... then no predecessor or successor of b is either.

But 9) the induction axiom does imply there are not distinct threads.

```
If K is a set such that:

0 is in K, and
for every natural number n, n being in K implies that S(n) is in K,

then K contains every natural number.
```

As K = 0->1->2->3 ... is such a set we have $\mathbb N \subset K \subset \mathbb N$ and 0->1->2->3.... are precisely the natural numbers and nothing else are.

This is not just theoretical.  1/2 ->1 1/2 -> 2 1/2 -> 3 1/2 $\not \subset \mathbb N$ is just such a separate string that *does* exist but are not the natural numbers.

I like to think (and I'm probably abusing some theory and I could be wrong) that 1-8 define the smallest thing the natural numbers can be.  And the induction axiom restricts it to the smallest it can be.  I may be naively abusing math though.