# Peano Axioms and loops

Tags: logic, arithmetic, peano-axioms

I want to know if the usual Peano axioms can really deal with "problems" like the following loop:

[image]

I honestly don't see the axioms avoid the last diagram.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: See the post: [are there natural numbers that are not the descendant of $0$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977555/are-there-natural-numbers-that-are-not-the-descendant-of-0)

Answer (score 5):

Consider the set of numbers $a$ with $SSSa\ne a$. That contains $0$ and is closed
under the successor operator. So it is all of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: +1. A quick comment for the OP: to see how you can come up with this, notice that the set of numbers "outside" the loop is an inductive set (= contains $0$ and is closed under successor) which is strictly smaller than the whole structure. Now what the induction scheme in PA does essentially is say that there are no **definable** inductive proper subsets of the universe, so what we want to do is cook up a definition of this proper inductive set. Thinking along these lines, we come up with the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

What about ordering ?

In $\mathsf {PA}$ we can define:

> $m < n \leftrightarrow \exists z \ (n=m+Sz)$.

Then, we can prove: $Sn=Sn+0=S(n+0)=n+S0$, and thus: $\exists z \ (Sn=n+Sz)$, i.e. $Sn>n$.

So, $SSSA > SSA > SA > A$, contradicting the fact that: $SSSA=A$.

Comment: I believe the question intends the *whole* diagram to be a putative picture of the natural numbers (or a subset thereof), rather than just the loop in the picture.

Comment: Sure, but "m<n↔∃z (n=m+Sz)" is not included in the axioms. Is that some kind of order axiom?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your point of view Samuel Diaz (the author of the question) because I had the same question:
The problem come from the anbigous way to define the 9th axiom of Peano (as you can see it from wikipedia for instance). It must be understood as :

Only N set which satisfy the next truth are really N set: for all set φ (or a unary predicate ie a set) such that:
 (φ(0) is true, and for every natural number n (belonging to set N), φ(n) being true implies that φ(S(n)) is true)
then φ(n) is true for every natural number n.

in other words: N must be a set for which all other sets φ for which (φ(0) and for all n belonging to N: φ(n)=> φ(s(n)) => φ are equal to N.

Indeed in N sets where loop exist, all φ sets which is true for (φ(0) and for all n belonging to N: φ(n)=> φ(s(n) ) (for instance a φ set have all true N numbers and no loops) are not true for ( φ = N) (in this case φ contain only the true n number, and N contains also loops!)