# About the proof by induction that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni(i+1)=\frac13n(n+1)(n+2)$ for $n\geq 1$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I'm trying to prove this by induction:

$$1*2 + 2*3 + 3*4 + \cdots + n(n+1) = (n(n+1)(n+2))/3.$$

I have done this so far:

Base Case:  $n = 1$, works for both.

Induction Hypothesis: Let $n = k$, such that:

$$1*2 + 2*3 + 3*4 + \cdots + k(k+1) = (k(k+1)(k+2))/3.$$

Inductive Step: Try $n = k+1$:

$$1*2 + 2*3 + 3*4 + \cdots+ k(k+1) + (k+1)(k+2) = (k(k+1)(k+2))/3.$$

Apparently it's a fallacy to write $k+1$ in LHS and RHS, so I'm doing the left; however, I'm stuck at this step and not sure where to go from here.

Comment: RHS should ve $(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)/3$.

Comment: I was told it's a falacy to plug in k+1 to both sides, you only work from one side. Unless I'm misinterpreting what my professor told me.

Comment: You have $LHS(k) + (k+1)(k+2) = \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3} + (k+1)(k+2) = (k+1)(k+2)(\frac{k}{3}+1)$. Is it clear?

Comment: That's clear, but is the falacy part correct? Or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: @user20842454566: I think the fallacy part that your professor talked about is clarified by what Daniel W. Farlow said in his first paragraph..

Comment: I recommend you learn classical first-order logic thoroughly, otherwise it is impossible to understand induction properly, and inevitably you will not be able to use it correctly except in extremely simple situations. Induction is **not at all** about following some fancy template like most textbooks and teachers will tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you do not really understand [why induction is a valid proof technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139579/why-is-mathematical-induction-a-valid-proof-technique/1139606#1139606) (it may also help to read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof/1255268#1255268) on how to write a clear induction proof). The "fallacy" you seem to have in mind does not make a great deal of sense; the goal of induction proofs (assuming you're trying to prove a statement $S(n)$ is true) is, indeed, to move from the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$ to the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$. It does not matter from which end you start (after all, if $x=y$, then $y=x$), but the important thing is that you use the induction assumption somewhere along the way. See if you can follow the proof below, and feel free to comment if a step does not make sense.

---

For $n\geq 1$, we want to show that
$$
1\cdot2+2\cdot3+\cdots+n(n+1)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}.\tag{1}
$$
To make $(1)$ more manageable, let's use [$\Sigma$-notation](http://www.statisticslectures.com/images/sigma2.gif) to rewrite it: 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}.
$$
Thus, for each $n\geq 1$, define the statement
$$
S(n) : \sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}.
$$

**Base step ($n=1$):** The statement $S(1)$ says that $1\cdot2=2=\frac{1(2)(3)}{3}$, and this is true.

**Inductive step ($S(k)\to S(k+1)$):** For some $k\geq 1$, assume that 
$$
S(k) : \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^ki(i+1)=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}}
$$
holds. To be shown is that
$$
S(k+1) : \color{green}{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i(i+1)=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}}
$$
follows. Starting with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$, 
\begin{align}
\color{green}{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i(i+1)} &= \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^ki(i+1)}+(k+1)(k+2)\tag{by defn. of $\Sigma$}\\[1em]
&= \color{blue}{\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}}+(k+1)(k+2)\tag{by $S(k)$, ind. hyp.}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\color{red}{k}(k+1)(k+2)}{3}+\frac{\color{red}{3}(k+1)(k+2)}{3}\tag{common denom.}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\color{red}{(k+3)}(k+1)(k+2)}{3}\tag{combine terms}\\[1em]
&= \color{green}{\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}},\tag{rearrange}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$, completing the inductive step.

Thus, by induction, the claim $S(n)$ holds for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Remarkable downvote: anyone care to explain why? Something I missed perhaps?

Comment: You wrote "the goal of induction proofs (assuming you're trying to prove a statement S(n)S(n) is true) is, indeed, to move from the left-hand side of S(k+1)S(k+1) to the right-hand side of S(k+1)". No that's not the goal of induction proofs. If you remove that I'll surely upvote your answer.

Comment: @user21820 I did not duplicate things as you have erroneously done. Also, of course the entire goal of induction proofs is not to move from the left hand side to the right hand side. Keep the audience/OP in mind. That is the goal here and there's no need to try to obfuscate the real objective by introducing more sophisticated, irrelevant ideas.

Comment: What I wrote in my answer is correct, not erroneous, so I can't see what you mean by "duplicate things". Yes I keep the audience in mind, but I am a teacher and through years of experience it is exactly this kind of left to right induction template that results in students not being able to grasp induction. In teaching mathematics the goal is to simplify as far as possible but not until it becomes false.

Comment: @user21820 Look at your first comment on my answer. I said nothing about "S(n)S(n)" being true or something about "S(k+1)S(k+1)." And in your answer you let $0\in\mathbb{N}$, something OP clearly does not have in mind. Also, you can use induction starting at a negative integer as a base case. Your answer is, at best, a reiteration of the pedagogical points of mine but without any help concerning the actual problem itself. I even provided links for OP to look at concerning why induction is a valid proof technique. I don't see how your answer is any more valuable than mine.

Comment: Sorry the LaTeX got deleted. I was merely trying to quote you, and I didn't notice the duplication until you pointed out.

Comment: In any case, I answer the actual underlying question and address the issue of logic that your answer does not. It is standard to take $0$ to be a natural number (except in popular math). Did you downvote despite it being correct?

Comment: @user21820 This is my last comment, as this does not seem to be a fruitful discussion--did you look at the first link I provided? That addresses *all* of the logical things you are talking about. And sure, many people include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$, but it is clear that OP, the person who actually asked the question, *did not*, and that is what is important here. It's not about satisfying your own pedantic niceties but rendering aid where it is needed, and I don't see how you did that. The goal is to help the questioner on his/her level, but I fail to see how your answer strives to do that.

Comment: Of course this is not a fruitful discussion. I've observed before that you have treated other people who criticise your answer in the same way. The fact is that your answer contains a falsehood, which you admit in your comment but refuse to change it despite the fact that I said I would upvote your answer if you removed it, whereas you have not stated one bit in my answer that is false. Even if I remove the part on $0$ being a natural number, you wouldn't be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $$\text{"$P(n)$ is true" is implied by}\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)=\frac {n(n+1)(n+2)}3$$ First we check for the base step: $1*(1+1)=2=\frac {1*(1+1)*(1+2)}3$

Hence $P(1)$ is true. Now assume that $P(k)$ is true for some $k \in N$. So $$\sum_{i=1}^ki(i+1)=\frac {k(k+1)(k+2)}3$$ Now we check for the truth of $P(k+1)$. $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i(i+1)&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^ki(i+1)\right)+(k+1)(k+2)\\&=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}3+(k+1)(k+2)\\&=(k+1)(k+2)(\frac k3+1)\\&=\frac {(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}3\end{align}$$ This is the RHS for $P(k+1)$. Hence $P(k)$ is true $\implies$ $P(k+1)$ is true. Therefore by the principle of mathematical induction $P(n)$ is true.

Well, if you are really determined to solve the question through induction, this is the way. But there is a much easier way to prove the equality. $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)&=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2+i=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+\frac{n(n+1)}2\\&=\frac16n(n+1)(2n+1+3)\\&=\frac 26n(n+1)(n+2)\\&=\frac {n(n+1)(n+2)}3\end{align}$$

Comment: Why are our answers being down voted for no reason? (+1)

Comment: Well your answer is indeed wrong because if you only assume $P(n) \Rightarrow ...$ then it is impossible and hence invalid to prove $P(k+1)$ true for whatever $k$. Why? Simply because there is an interpretation (read up on logic) that evaluates $P(n)$ to $false$ for every natural number $n$ which satisfies your "$P(n) \Rightarrow ...$" but not your conclusions, which implies that your argument is unsound.

Comment: @user21820: I didn't understand my flaw in the solution from what you said... nevertheless I have edited the solution a little. Can you explain me your interpretation of what I've written that seems wrong to you. I am just a student studying in $12th$ standard and hence don't have knowledge enough to contradict you...

Comment: You need to learn a little bit of logic first. I know that you aren't taught logic properly in high-school, but all I can say is that you shouldn't use symbols like "$\Rightarrow$" without understanding them properly. "$A \Rightarrow B$" asserts exactly "If $A$, then $B$". So you are making a basic logical fallacy (converse error) if you have "$A \Rightarrow B$" and "$B$" and then assert "$A$". One website that I found that should be a good introduction is http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/content/logic/intr_to_logic.html. It is not standard mathematical logic but close enough.

Comment: If you have any other questions about logic, feel free to ask a new question and ping me in a comment if you want me to answer.

Comment: Oh, I actually knew that, just that I wrote something grossly wrong in a hurry and didn't really care about what I had written, thinking the OP would understand anyway, well I will edit it..... and ....high schools in India don't teach induction.. i mean completely, they just leave it at the basics...

Answer (score 0):

The fallacy your professor is referring to is that you wrote down a statement that is false (even in its context).

The induction step is always to prove something of the form:

> For any natural number $n$, **if** $P(n)$ is true, **then** $P(n+1)$ is true.

where $P$ is the property that you want to prove about every natural number.

You start by proving that $0$ satisfies $P$. That's fine.

But in the induction step, you are given some (unknown) natural number $n$ and you are given the fact that $n$ satisfies $P$. So while proving the induction step all you can use is $P(n)$. You must not claim $P(n+1)$ until you have proven it. It would have been okay if you had said:

> Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k(k+1) = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$, **we want to prove** $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} k(k+1) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{3}$, which would be equivalent to $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3} + (n+1)(n+2) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{3}$, which is true because...

This is how we can break down the task of proving the induction step, and is called a top-down approach, but you must be careful to distinguish between what you are given or have proven and what you have not proven.

However, your professor is wrong if he/she said you should only work from one side, since in more complicated problems it is usually the easiest to work from both sides and meet in the middle. This is a simple but useful technique especially if combined with the concept of 'reducing' both sides in some manner to similar form. He/she might be purposely over-simplifying the issue, though, since easy induction problems all involve proving an equality/inequality that can be done from one side to the other. Hard problems can be impossible to humanly solve without manipulating multiple pieces at the same time.

Comment: What could be a motive to downvote this? (Sighs...)