# Concrete Mathematics problem 1.9c proof by contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

I'm self-studying the Concrete Mathematics book and I'm trying to work through the following problem:

> Consider the following statement:
>
> $ P(n): x_1 ... x_n \leq \left( \frac{x_1 + ... + x_n}{n}\right)^n$ ,
> if $ x_1, ..., x_n \geq 0 $
>
> This is true when $n = 2$, since $(x_1 + x_2)^2 - 4x_1x_2 = (x_1 - x_2)^2 \geq 0$.
>
> a) By setting $x_n = \frac{x_1 + ... + x_{n-1}}{n-1}$, prove that
> $P(n) \implies P(n-1)$ whenever $n > 1$.
>
> b) Show that $P(n)$ and $P(2)$ imply $P(2n)$
>
> c) Explain why this implies the truth of $P(n)$ for all $n$.

I've already done the first two parts, but I'm trying to reason about why (c) is true. I guess it's because the question asks us to *explain* why this implies truth for all $n$ instead of *prove* it, but I'm not satisfied with the book's answer. I've attempted to come up with my own rigorous proof to convince myself of this assertion inspired by this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1139606/870971). I'm wondering, would this be a valid proof by contradiction to show that $P(n)$ is true for all $n$?

**Proof by Contradiction**

Assume there is a non-empty set $S = \lbrace s \in \mathbb{N} | P(s) \text{ is false } \rbrace $.

Due to the well-ordering principle, we know that $S$ must have a minimum if it is non-empty. Let's take the minimum to be $s_0 = \text{min}(S)$. Because we know the base case P(2) is true, $s_0 > 2$.

Since $s_0$ is the minimum of set $S$, $\forall x \in [2, n), P(x)$ is true.

Without loss of generality, assume that $s_0$ is odd as it can be easily proven if $s_0$ is even. $P \left( \frac{s_0+1}{2} \right)$ is true since $\frac{s_0+1}{2} < s_0$ for $s_0 > 1$ and we've established that $s_0 > 2$.

Since $ P(n) \land P(2) \implies P(2n)$, $P(\frac{s_0+1}{2}) \land P(2) \implies P(s_0 + 1)$. Thus, $P(s_0+1)$ must be true.

Because $ P(n) \implies P(n-1)$ when $n > 1$, $P(s_0+1) \implies P((s_0 + 1) - 1) = P(s_0)$. Thus, $P(s_0)$ must be true.

However, this contradicts our assumption that there is a minimum of $S$, $s_0 = \text{min}(S)$. Thus, if there is no minimum of $S$, $S = \emptyset$ and there are no $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P(x)$ is false.

Comment: Your proof is fine, but a little overboard for the task. A simpler proof would be as follows: Suppose that there exists some $m$ for which $P$ doesn't hold. Then, let $n$ be the smallest such natural. There are two such cases: If $n$ is even, then $P(n/2)$ is true by minimality, and hence, $P(n)$ is true, a contradiction. If $n$ is odd, then $P((n+1)/2)$ is true since $n>1$ and hence, $n>(n+1)/2$. So, $P(n+1)$ is true, and so, $P(n+1-1)=P(n)$ is true, a contradiction.

Comment: Why do you claim that it can be easily proved if $s_0$ is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct, if a bit over-complicated. And I would not say that you can assume **without loss of generality** that $s_0$ is odd: the argument in the even case is pretty trivial, but an argument is required.

Alternatively, one can observe that it follows from (b) by a trivial induction that $P(2^n)$ holds for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and it follows from (a) by an equally easy (downward) induction that if $2\le m\le n$, and $P(n)$ holds, then $P(m)$ holds. Since for each $m\ge 2$ there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $m\le 2^n$, the result follows.